# Save Image to Vertical with Android Studio and ImageView

Tags: java, android-studio, camera, imageview

One question, there is a way to be able to capture a photograph and save it in vertical mode whenever
Whether taken in Horizontal or Vertical?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix rotations of image according to your requirement.

Here is a sample:

```
ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(photoPath);
int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                                     ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

switch(orientation) {

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 90);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 180);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
        rotateImage(bitmap, 270);
        break;

    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:

    default:
        break;
}
```